# Flutter - Bluetooth Package which enables Bluetooth service

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I am trying to build a Bluetooth application using flutter but I face some challenges like check whether the Bluetooth service is enabled or disabled if not need to give access or permission to switch it on from the application and also I am using this package `flutter_blue 0.4.2` in which I can scan nearby devices only when I enable GPS location. So, please help me out in which way I can achieve all those challenges and build a Bluetooth application. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think, through flutter_blue pkg it is NOT possible to enable/disable Bluetooth. You need to send a platform channel to achieve this. About GPS, even I am surprised why. they really need GPS?

Answer (score 0):

When using BLE (Bluetooth low emissions), location/GPS services are needed as @alejo9719 mentioned [here](https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue/issues/336#issuecomment-712222683).

Regarding switching on/off bluetooth in the application, I suggest taking a look at [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bluetooth_serial). It's not a BLE package, but it has implemented the turn on/off bluetooth feature inside the app.